# Run my code in already existing and running thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm using 3rd party which drawing to a view something.

I got the process threads list and i found the thread they are using to draw their stuff in.

I want to add my drawing code in this thread - meaning when they are finishing drawing their stuff in the thread then my code will run and then the thread will end (or whatever happens with it).

I tried to do my drawing code in different thread and UI Thread but I can see that my drawing is running after the 3rd party when we change the camera position.

Is it possible to inject some code into another thread? btw, I have only their Thread object in my hand which i got from running over all the threads list.
If not, other solution will be fine also (if there is)

**-- EDIT --**

Tried to `suspend` their thread, draw my stuff, and `resume`, but it is crashing - guess due to those are deprecated functions

Comment: is their thread uses an interface to notify anything?

Comment: No.. Nothing. They just want the developers to work with their drawing objects (and they will control the drawing). But the set of objects are not good enough for my custom drawing

Comment: What is that 3rd party?

Comment: **esri** - It's a gis infrastructure

Comment: i think they should provide an interface or something for you to work with

Comment: I know that they should :) The thing is that they are one of the biggest GIS company in world and getting versions and updates takes time and most of the time they decide not to do it. So I insist to find away here :) I've managed to do it in their javascript version, and now i want to do it in the mobile

Comment: Not sure it's possible to do this without a hook, the UI thread has no priorities when it comes to drawing jobs...

Comment: There is away to tell the other thread to pause and resume (and in the middle i will draw mine)?

Answer (score 0):

Purely theoretical stuff ahead:

Check if they support drawing to backbuffer (not screen) -- OR -- try to redirect drawing to a backbuffer(framebuffer). Do your drawing in the backbuffer too. Manually switch backbuffer (actually back framebuffer) with front framebuffer.

They are most probably doing their drawing in a loop. The onDraw may be event triggered or it just tries to provide as much fps as it can. But if you synchronize the access to your backbuffer, you may force their draw thread to wait exactly for the time you do your drawing and the swap of buffers. You need to initially sync your procedure with theirs (probably by painfully testing that your code gets to run from time to time, and drawing is not blocked). And you must remember that if this work, the synchronization will mean that their thread will wait on their N loop for the end of your N-1 loop at exactly the first operation working with the backbuffer.